# Android pass credentials to other app

Tags: android, single-sign-on, share, ipc

Currently I am searching for possible ways of passing credentials to other application without specifying URI. Let me describe the flow:

1. User opens my application and Login view is displayed
2. User enters his/her credentials into the form (e.g. email / password)
3. My application finds the desired app (lets assume this is Facebook), finds com.facebook.katana package and prepares Intent for it.
4. **Here comes the answer to question: how to pass credentials?**
5. or I put those credentials into Intent as extra with specific Intent action
6. Facebook app is opened and users credentials are passed into Facebook login form and user is authenticated.

Please, do not provide answers related to SDK usages (e.g. "Use Facebook SDK to authenticate into Facebook). I need generic solution for authenticating into applications selected by user with provided credentials by the user.

Let me know if this is possible and how to achieve without extra changes on the partners app to handle specific URI. Thanks!

Comment: "I need generic solution for authenticating into applications selected by user" - What makes you think that arbitrary applications will allow authentication through an Intent, or any other mechanism besides keyboard entry?

Comment: @JimmyB Android accessibility makes me think so. I do not say that his SHOULD be Intent, maybe there are other ways I do not know about...